# Google Maps: bind click event or info window to OverlayView

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Any ideas on how to bind a click event to an OverlayView in v3 of the GMaps API?  The overlays seem to be buried under the map's panes so clicking on the overlay results in just a zoom.  I'd ultimately like to bind an infowindow to the overlay but just being able to click it would be a fine start.

Would just changing the z-index be the way to go?  I tried this for a little while but couldn't get through all of the nested divs loaded by the map.

This is the demo I'm playing with: [dutrack.com/markerShapes.php](http://dutrack.com/markerShapes.php).

Edit: The overlays on the demo map are the large 'teardrop' icons and the paths.  The smaller blue icons are Markers at the moment.

Comment: +1 for posting a link to your example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider placing your overlays in a different pane so that their z-Index is higher than. According to the documentation, `getPanes().floatPane` will get you the pane which is above all other map panes.

Also give your overlays a high z-Index so that they appear above other content in this frame.

Then use `google.maps.event.addDomListener(..)` to attach a click listener to your custom overlay.